# What are the downsides of Remote Control?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, drones

I want to create a Rigger, and spare on Agility.
RAW if I use *Remote Control* I can shoot with Gunnery + Logic (according to Gunnery, p183), but with *Rigger Control* I have to use Gunnery + Agility.

What do I lose if I stick to Remote Control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, whether you use Gunnery + Agility or Logic for remote control is contested, [see this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59381/how-does-gunnery-work-when-jumped-in). If the abilities used in RC and rig-in differ, that is one thing you lose or gain, depending on your perspective/character. What is sure is that:

### You lose 1 die and a limit bonus

When jumped into a drone and in hot-sim, you can apply the +1 bonus to matrix actions to vehicle actions too, including firing mounted weapons.

Also, while the test uses the lower of your Data Proc. or the usual limit for the test (Accuracy here), you can add your control rig rating to it when jumped in.

Both rules can be found on page 266 of the Core Rulebook.

Comment: Gunnery (p183): "Vehicle-mounted weapons are fired using [...] Gunnery + Logic [Accuracy] for remote operated systems"

Comment: @András Then we have two rules that contradict each other. Which one wins?

Comment: @Szega this [other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59381/how-does-gunnery-work-when-jumped-in) might interest you.

Comment: @ShadowKras Yes, they cite the rules in conflict too. Having one upvoted does not solve it in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, we don't have an official answer, but you could address both scenarios. The OP seems to be assuming that Gunnery+Logic is a possibility, and not that you always will use Gunnery+Agility, as he wants to dump his Agility in favor of high Logic.

Comment: @ShadowKras Actually, the answer to the question here is still valid. Whether you use Agi or Lgc is out of the scope of this question. I will edit to show the controversy.

Comment: @Szega Passive Targeting also writes Gunnery + Logic. Agility makes no sense anyway, you don't use your muscles when you are working in virtual, otherwise every rigger would just buy Muscle Replacement.